# animation in knitr document with ggplot figures

Tags: r, animation, ggplot2, knitr

I am trying to use the following chunk in my knitr document that creates a pdf

```
<<animate_gg,fig.show='animate', eval=TRUE>>=
gg.list<-list()
for (w.it in w.vals){
sub.final.pts.lf.logical<-all.final.pts.lf$w %in% w.it
sub.final.pts.lf<- all.final.pts.lf[sub.final.pts.lf.logical,]
levels(sub.final.pts.lf$w)<- paste("w=",levels(sub.final.pts.lf$w))

g1<-ggplot(sub.final.pts.lf,aes(x=x,y=y,colour=pt.name))+geom_point(alpha = 1/5) +scale_shape(solid = FALSE)
gg.list<-c(gg.list,list(g1))
}
for (gg in gg.list){
gg  
}
```

however this doesn't create any corresponding section in latex. I assume the problem is that if I use `gg`  inside  brackets, R doesn't evaluate that line.The following creates the animation with one plot

```
 {
g1<-ggplot(sub.final.pts.lf,aes(x=x,y=y,colour=pt.name))+geom_point(alpha = 1/5) +scale_shape(solid = FALSE)

}
g1
```

How do I create an animation with all of the created plots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [top FAQ (7.22)](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-do-lattice_002ftrellis-graphics-not-work_003f) for grid-based graphics: `print(gg)`

Comment: That works. Now I have a different problem, where the generated plots for the animation  are all the same (in figures/animate_gg{1-36}.pdf)  . If I choose fig.show='as.is' , I get different plots as expected.